LEDs driven by constant-current drivers to light up like AND gates with the same intensity
Suppose that A and B in the image is connected to the two output pins of LED driver, which can be independently switched on and off a constant current of 30 mA.
I want LED D3 to be turned on only when both D1 and D2 are ON.
I also want the current that goes through D3 to be 30 mA when it's ON, so that it emits light with the same intensity as D1 and D2.
My questions are:

Could you please check if my circuit work as I desire (i.e., if D1, D2, and D3 mimic AND gate and emit light with the same intensity)?
Is there any idea to make the circuit simpler with fewer components? Or do you know if there is an IC chip that integrates n-type MOSFETs and resistors in the way shown in my circuit?

I am a beginner and any help would be appreciated.


Whether it works depends heavily on the design of the LED drivers. Those are massive 70A MOSFETs however they are not well specified at less than 10V Vgs and could require as much as 4V to conduct only 1mA at room temperature. It's not all that common to have a high-side current source driver, are you sure that's what  you have? And if so, what is the compliance voltage (the maximum voltage to maintain the current minus the LED forward voltage?

Oh no, I made a mistake. That’s just a random part number that the software selected and I have not yet purchased MOSFET.
I just first wanted to check if the logic of the circuit is correct; please ignore the part number of MOSFET.

Do you have by any chance have a suggestion of MOSFET part number to be used?

I would hesitate to offer suggestions without the information requested.

Here is the LEDs I am going to use:https://downloads.cree-led.com/files/ds/h/HB-CLM1B-BKW-GKW.pdf please let me know if I’m not providing enough information.

And a LED driver: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/tlc5947.pdf

Okay, so the LEDs are actually connected to some voltage VLED rather than ground .. which is what voltage?  And just one LED or more in series? And you are using the PWM function?

Sorry, that's another mistake on my side. Yes, anode of LEDs have to be connected to VLED, and cathodes should be connected to the LED driver, if I use TLC5947.
I'm going to connect 4 LEDs in series on each pins of the driver. There are 24 pins on the driver, so 96 LEDs in total. Additionally, I have 48 (2 by 24) LEDs (corresponding to D3), and 2 LEDs each are placed between each pair of driver pins (2 LEDs between pins 0 and 23 as well)..
Power supply is 24V, and I think the driver does the PWM to control the intensity of LED.

I think the following circuit will do what you want, but I haven't tested it physically. It's a lot simpler than yours (which I believe would work, by the way), requiring no additional power supply, and only one P-channel MOSFET:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Ignore Da and Db, they simply constrain the voltage of the two current sources, and don't form part of the built unit, shown right.
It works in simulation, but I would wait for feedback from others to point out any flaws, before you actually install it.
Q1 will be switched off when gate and source potentials are similar, or the gate exceeds the source. This occurs when SW1 is closed, which raises gate potential. If SW2 is also closed, current flows via both D2 and D3.
With SW1 open, gate potential is held near 0V by R1, permitting Q1 to switch on, and shunt current around D3. D1 has very high impedance in this state, and won't hold the gate firmly at ground. R1 is necessary to attenuate any pick-up that might otherwise appear at the gate.
Therefore, D3 only lights when SW1 is closed (Q1 is off), and SW2 is closed too.
This relies upon all the LEDs having approximately the same forward voltage \$V_F\$. It also requires that \$V_F << V_{GS(MAX)}\$. In this case I've assumed \$V_F=12V\$, which would be well within the 20V limit for many MOSFETs.
This won't work well if these are single LEDs, with \$V_F\$ comparable with \$V_{GS(TH)}\$. In that case you'll have to artificially increase the \$V_F\$ of D1 and D3 with a series resistance, or zener diodes:

simulate this circuit
One problem with this design is that when Q1 is on, it self-biases to have \$V_{DS}\approx V_{GS(TH)}\$, which means that there is still a small voltage (approximately equal to the MOSFET's gate-source threshold voltage) across LED D3. While this will cause only a very small current, of the order of microamps, it's probably enough to make D3 glow slightly.
Here's a fix for that, using the zener diodes from above:

simulate this circuit
R2 to draws enough current via D5 to cause it to develop the lion's share of that voltage. There may be better ways to solve this problem.
The caveat for R1 and R2 is of course that LED currents will be slightly reduced, but it's such a small change that you shouldn't notice it.

Thank you, that is a great circuit I could not have thought of on my own. This may be a dumb question, but how is the off status of Q1 guaranteed when both SW1 and SW2 are closed? Since A and B are constant current, not constant voltage, I do not know how to calculate $V_{GS}$.

@matcha $V_{GS(TH)}$ comes from the MOSFET's datasheet. It's usually about 2V or 3V or so. The voltages present everywhere are mostly determined by the LEDs' forward voltage $V_F$. In this case it's the voltage across an LED when 30mA flows through it. You can measure it easily enough. This is the only "guarantee" you have, and is why I claimed early on that everything is heavily dependent upon $V_F$ being similar for all LEDs.

Ah, now I understand. Thank you!

If you ensure stable 5V supply you can avoid Led drivers and use a 68 ohm limiting resistors instead.
An AND gate form a 1K/1K/4k7 resistors here.
When both D1&D2 are supplied the transistor conducts and connects the D3.


The circuit in the original question should work fine.
To simplify, you can delete R2, R4 and R5.  Connect the Q1 gate directly to the R1 / D1 node.  Connect the Q2 gate directly to the Q1 drain.  Not counting the LEDs, this brings the total number of connected pins down to 10.
R1 = 330 ohms.  At 30 mA, this limits the Q1 Vgs to 10 V, a safe value for most "normal" MOSFETs.
R3 = 10 K.
Consider a 2N7000 for the FETs.

I see, I was thinking I may be able to remove R2 and R5, but now I understand that R4 can also be removed.
That's simpler. Info for the specific values of resistors and FETs is also helpful, thank you so much!

Okay, if I take your circuit and flip it upside down to accommodate the LED connections with the TLC5947 and 24V VLED that you are using, and add a bit of circuitry and much smaller MOSFETS to protect the gates and get them to switch fast (the PWM clock frequency is nominally 4MHz, which yields 1/4096 of that to the LEDs) then it should work!
Larger MOSFETs would require more circuitry to drive the gates that fast.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Again, this is essentially your circuity with some tweaks-

Due to the relatively fast PWM clock, I suggest testing it at an early stage though, just in case something has been missed or the human eye response makes things look different than you expect.

Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense and I will adopt it. Following your suggestion, I'll test with minimum components and will apply it with ~100 LEDs that I need eventually.
It must be very basic, but could you tell me a bit about the function of D4, D5, and R2?

D4/C1/R2 creates a voltage 6 or 7V below 24V for two purposes- to drive the gate of M3 through R3 and to act as a clamp for the gate of M1 through D5. D5 is used rather than just connecting a zener from gate to source to improve switching speed.

I see, thank you so much!
